# How to draw text second time without shadow?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I use HTML5 canvas to draw the text. The text changes color after some time. I would like to keep its shadow unchanged. But if I call `fillText()` several times, then transparent shadow is drawn again and again and in result I have dark shadow:

I've tried to assigned `undefined` values to according shadow properties, but it doesn't help:

```
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)";
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
ctx.shadowBlur = 30;

var text = 'Sample text with shadow';
ctx.fillText(text,0,100); // the shadow is drawn first time

ctx.shadowColor = undefined;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = undefined;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = undefined;
ctx.shadowBlur = undefined;
... // color text is changed here etc.
ctx.fillText(text,0,100); // the shadow is drawn several times
ctx.fillText(text,0,100);
ctx.fillText(text,0,100);
```

See [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/zk2hyca9/1/).

How could I fix it?

Comment: undefined is ignored. Use null / 0 / false / ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the shadow color transparent instead of 'undefined':

```
ctx.shadowColor = 'transparent';  // or any zero-alpha color
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
```